# Converting generic ArrayList to Array

Tags: arrays, generics, arraylist

**Am trying to convert the List returned by the DataBaseHandler to an Array.I get an error**

```
final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(MainCourseList.this);
List<coursedb>  contacts = db.getAllContacts(); //getting all records from database as a List
Collections.sort(elements);
images=pics.toArray(new String[pics.size()]);
String[] itemArray = new String[contacts.size()]; //converting the LIst to array
titles= contacts.toArray(itemArray);

descriptions = elements.toArray(new String[elements.size()]);

rowItemps = new ArrayList<CourseItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++)
{
    CourseItem item = new CourseItem(descriptions[i],images[i],titles[i]);// using the array values to add to listView
    rowItemps.add(item);
}

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clist);
adapter = new CourseAdapter(this, rowItemps);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to dump a list of `coursedb` into an array of `String`?

Comment: CourseDB is NOT a String. Of course it crashes. Also, I'm not sure why you didn't post the actual error. Nor what the type of `descriptions` is, for example. I don't have enough data of the code to actually tell you what to do to fix it.